# Trying to understand token creation in Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am looking at Tenx token on the ethereum platform:
https://etherscan.io/token/TenXPay

Here's what I understand, total supply - 205,218,255.9485

Now when I go to: coinmarketcap.com/assets/tenx/

It tells me 104,661,31 in circulation.

So my questions are:

1. Any ideas on why the total supply is not rounded up? Something to do with the code?
2. How do I find total token sold during the ICO? I see the balance by going to:

etherscan.io/token/tokenholderchart/0xB97048628DB6B661D4C2aA833e95Dbe1A905B280

and it shows 49% supply held by a single account. 
So should I assume only that the 51% supply has been sold and rest is still held in the account? 
Will it be true for other tokens too? Because QTUM shows me:

etherscan.io/token/tokenholderchart/0x9a642d6b3368ddc662CA244bAdf32cDA716005BC

3. How do I find the token creator address? Will it be same as the highest token holder?
4. Any ideas on how do I pull this info for NXT and OMNI platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The token balance is not rounded up because that is not what the creator defined when instantiating the contract.

As shown [here](https://etherscan.io/token/TenXPay#readContract) they chose an initial supply of `205218255948577763364408207` with `18` decimal places. I.E `205,218,255.9485` tokens.

2. You can wait until they release a detailed report. They say they will do [here](https://www.tenx.tech/tokensale.html). That link you posted shows an allocation but assumes that at this point all the tokens have been distributed.

Each token will have a different distribution model and your best bet is to read their [sourcecode](https://etherscan.io/address/0xB97048628DB6B661D4C2aA833e95Dbe1A905B280#code), and their PR to discern what they have done.

3. [This page](https://etherscan.io/token/TenXPay) says the contract address is [0xB97048628DB6B661D4C2aA833e95Dbe1A905B280](https://etherscan.io/address/0xB97048628DB6B661D4C2aA833e95Dbe1A905B280).

On this page you can see that the contract creator was [0xd43d09ec1bc5e57c8f3d0c64020d403b04c7f783](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd43d09ec1bc5e57c8f3d0c64020d403b04c7f783).

4. NXT and OMNI have nothing to do with Ethereum.

Comment: 1. Any ideas on why did they chose the initial supply at such an order number?

Comment: I understand NXT and OMNI are different platforms, I am just wondering if someone can point me to a similar break down on those platforms.

Comment: People on here are unlikely to know about those platforms as this site is solely dedicated to Ethereum. If this answer helped you, please click the check mark.